# Optimizing sales problem in excel/google sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, data-analysis, business-intelligence

I have a table that looks like that: 
[image]

The p1,p2,p3 are different platforms that I can advertise on. 
The most left column is how much I will invest in a platform, the values are the total sales that I will get from a platform if I will invest the money on the most lest column. 
For example, if I'm investing 1000 in p1 I will get 100 sales. 
My problem is given a budget of 20000, how should I split it between the platforms such that I will have the maximum sales. 
For example, 15000 on p1 + 5000 on p2 + 5000 on p3 will give me 1500 + 90 + 140 = 1730 sales.
I tried to think how can I do it in google sheets (or excel), is it possible to solve this optimization only with formulas? Or maybe I should use solver somehow, I'm pretty new to this so I'm kind of stuck. 
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: As far as I am aware the Solver is in Excel, not google sheets.

Comment: There is an add-on for google sheets. Anyhow, if there is a way to solve this without solver it will be better.

Comment: Good, so here is a tutorial for you: https://nathanbrixius.wordpress.com/2014/10/14/optimization-in-google-sheets/  My issue is that you have to be on the Cloud - Solver in Excel works on the machhine..

Comment: set up three cells to represent the amount of money you would invest in each of the three categories.  In a fourth cell place a formula that is the sum of the three investments (total).  In an adjacent three cells to the first three use a lookup or index/match to find the return amounts.  In another cell get the sum of the return values.  In your solver, set the first three investment cells as variables.  Set a constraint that the the investment total is either 20K or less than or equal to 20K.  Set the return total cell to be maximized.

Comment: Thanks! I think it's almost there but I get "An error occurred during the computation of the derivatives." error. Is there a way to make him change the variable cells from the set of investments (1000,2000,3000...20000)? I think maybe he tries some values that does not translate in my vlookup.

Comment: if you set you match or look up to not be exact than the only thing you need to verify is that a value of 0 is not tossing an error.  You may need to expand your table to include a zero value.and add a constraint that the minimum investment value is 0 and the number must be positive.

Comment: If you cant expand your table, you could wrap your lookup match function in an IFERROR function that returns a 0 in the event of an error.  You want to verify first though what is causing the error